# Spring in-memory database

Tags: spring, hibernate

I have a Spring project using Hibernate. The DB is generated based on the models and their annotations. For testing purposes, I would like to set up a in-memory DB.

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase db = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScript("???").build();
}
```

How can I get the script that is generated by Hibernate programatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean `hbm2ddl` feature of Hibernate? You don't have to pass the script explicitly. If this feature is enabled, Hibernate will automatically run the script on a provided `DataSource` (`EmbeddedDatabase` actually implements `DataSource`). No manual work needed.